# use jquery to disable mouse scroll wheel function when the mouse cursor is inside a div?

Tags: jquery

How to use jquery to disable mouse scroll wheel function that scrolling the long page when the mouse is pointing inside a div?

I need to disable it because I have another mouse scroll wheel function inside the div, if the page is too long, when i scroll my mouse wheel inside the div, the div and the page both will be scrolled. I don't want both of them be scrolled, i want inside div be scrolled only.

Comment: Can you show your custom function?  You need to add `event.stopPropagation()`, but will need to make sure you're defining the event argument.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

problem is solved, i just changed the css of body and div and it works!! Happy. LOL.