# Make script affect on dynamic loaded content

Tags: jquery

I found this script here at Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7571867/2518302

When put that code in a normal:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { Script });
```

.. the script runs good. The problem is that its not affect dynamic loaded content at the site, so if having a div that loads in dynamic (after pageload) the script dont work at that div.

Then if trigger the script to run again at the same time as the dynamic content loads the already existing divs using this script on the page gets the script for its second time since pageload (script executed once at pageload and once at dynamic load). The results of that is that all the divs that got the script twice scroll at double speed.

Is there any way to just execute the script at pageload and make it affect both content thats on page since pageload and later dynamic loaded content?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: use delegation with .on()  check doc for syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `on` jQuery function.

```
$(document).on("event", "selectorOfDynamicElements", function() {
     // do something 
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9pR87/75/)

In the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) we find this:

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )

So in the example we will detect clicks on `document` with these parameters:

- `events`: "click"
- `selector`: ".myFavoriteClass"

### Direct and delegated events

When a selector **is provided**, the event handler **is referred to as delegated**. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector.

**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to** `.on()`. To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page.

---

[read more on the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)]

---

The issue in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uat6C/5/) is that you create binds to every `mouseover`.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.test', function () {
    // the mouseover is detected, "Hey, create a new handler!"
    $('.test').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
          // "Ok, sir. Here your code goes"
    });
});
```

Instead of the code above you should simply have:

```
$(document).on('mouseover mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', '.test', function (e) {
     // here your code goes
});
```

[**Updated FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uat6C/7/)

Comment: If write like this "$(document).on('mouseover', '.div_associated_with_script', function () { Script });" the script works but its executes strange, the scroll scrolls 2-3 times as fast as usually to all divs associated with the script (both divs existed from pageload and dynamic loaded). Should the event not be "mouseover"?

Comment: I think it is the mouseover event that is wrong in this situation, look at this jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/Uat6C/5. When hover with mouse in the "result" box then scroll in the div the scroll is very fast after a while. Then what event to add?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately now the scripts functions dident work anymore.

Comment: The scripts main function is to prevent the the main-page (body) to scroll when scroll to the bottom of the div (when hover mouse in div its impossible to scroll main-page). Unfortunately that function dident work anymore.

Comment: @Vode It's my mistake, sorry. You see 'e is undefined'. Thanks. Updating my answer.

Comment: @Vode And `mouseover` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` and delegate to an element that is present when the page loads.

For example, if the dynamically created `div` that is not present on page load looks like this

```
<div id="dynamic"></div>
```

Your `JS` would look like this

```
$(body).on(event, '#dynamic', function(){ Script });
```

Where `event` is equal to `click`, `mousedown`, etc.

Comment: If write like this "$(document).on('mouseover', '.div_associated_with_script', function () { Script });" the script works but its executes strange, the scroll scrolls 2-3 times as fast as usually to all divs associated with the script (both divs existed from pageload and dynamic loaded). Should the event not be "mouseover"?